# New product: Rode Lavalier Mic

Tags: lavalier, new, microphone, product

I just popped into the Rode site to check specs on the NT5 and lo and behold:
http://www.rodemicrophones.com/microphone.php?product=lavalier

They have just released the Rode lavalier mic!  Anyone planning on getting this or perhaps already have one?  I'd love to see a review/comparison of the Rode lav vs something like the Sennheiser MKH2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just received the RODE Lavalier for testing. I did compare it with the Sennheiser MKE-2, if that is the model you're referring to. The MKE-2 is still a bit brighter. You can listen to the lav against a Tram and Sanken COS11 here http://www.dvestore.com/news/8/Lavalier-Shootout-%252d-RODE%2C-Sanken-COS11D%2C-Tram-TR50%2C-and-Sennheiser-ME2.html

Comment: @guycochran Thanks for the video link, was very informative

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be retailing for $250 or so.  Not bad price-wise, but most wireless packs will come with a larger lapel mic like that.  Might as well spend $70 more and get a great sounding, tiny Countryman B6.

Disclaimer:  I don't do interviews or docs, only narrative film sound, so I don't really use lapels.  I do use them in life production sound, but use Countryman E6s for that.

Comment: Yip, I'd love to own some Countryman B6's but damn, down south here on the tip of africa, they are a wee bit expensive!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good mic and I would like a couple, my only concern at the moment is the frequency range which is 60Hz - 18kHz which is a lot less lower end than other lavs. How much of an issue this will be regarding dialogue I am not sure. It seemed to sound fairly nice on the vid posted above.

Comment: @Lenny I agree, it looks like a great little mic.  I don't think the 60Hz-18kHz is too much to worry about, I mean how many people do you know that can hear above the 17kHz-20kHz range?  The low end of 60Hz doesn't bother me too much either, thats low end rumble and the sound you don't really want to hear for dialogue anyway.
I am just not certain about the S/N of 69dB...is that good?

Comment: Yes I think that is fine, many good quality lavs have a similar signal to noise ratio.